# I want to select my dataset on the basis of certain characters in a particular column. How can I do that in R?

Tags: r

Suppose a column in my data is `Time<-c(2012, 2013, 2012m1, 2012m2, 2012m3, 2012q1, 2012q2, 2012q3)`. And there are other columns with variables pertaining to these elements. I want to trim my data on the basis of column `Time` but using only those elements that have `m` or `q` in them. How can this be done in R?

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
data <- data.frame(Time = c("2012", "2012m1", "2013q1", "2014"),
                   Values = c(1, 2, 3, 4))

data[grep("m|q", data$Time),]
```